# Display dialog using buttons in other components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my vue2 app I have a parent component with several child components. One such child component (I'll refer to it as PaymentComponent) is a simple dialog for capturing payment information.

Currently, there are a couple places in the application where it makes sense to display the payment dialog. However, I'm having trouble understanding how to display the dialog in PaymentComponent using buttons in other child components.

Below is the PaymentComponent. Any tips on how I can display the dialog using a button from another component which shares the same parent component?

```
<template>
    <v-dialog v-model="paymentDialog" max-width="500">
        <card
            class='stripe-card'
            :class='{ complete }'
            stripe='pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            :options='stripeOptions'
            @change='complete = $event.complete'>
        </card>

        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn color="green darken-1" flat="flat" @click.native="paymentDialog = false">Disagree</v-btn>
        <v-btn color="green darken-1" flat="flat" class="pay-with-stripe"  @click='pay' :disabled='!complete'>Agree</v-btn>
    </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
    // import { stripeKey, stripeOptions } from './stripeConfig.json'
    import { Card, createToken } from 'vue-stripe-elements-plus'

    export default {
        name: 'stripe-payment',

        data () {
            return {
                complete: false,
                stripeOptions: {
                    // see https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#element-options for details
                },
                stripeKey: '',
                paymentDialog: false
            }
        },

        components: { Card },

        methods: {
            pay () {
                // createToken returns a Promise which resolves in a result object with
                // either a token or an error key.
                // See https://stripe.com/docs/api#tokens for the token object.
                // See https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors for the error object.
                // More general https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#stripe-create-token.
                createToken().then(data => console.log(data.token))
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: please show `v-dialog` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So you want to open the modal from anywhere in the application.

One solution will be with `event bus` ([see more here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/)), in which you can emit an event from every component and listen to that event in modal component.

Another solution is to use `vuex`([see more here](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex)) in which you can toggle(true, false) a property on store and listen to modal component(has to be global component) to open or close the modal.

Anyway, i had something similar to your situation and used a great library which worked perfect for me and with it you can:

1- open the modal using `this.$modal.show('name-of-modal')`

2- hide the modal using `this.$modal.hide('name-of-modal')`

3- Instead of modal you can use dialog and dynamic components too

For more [read the docs](https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal)

Comment: The event bus worked perfectly! Thanks for the recommendations!

Comment: Glad to help you.But still my recommandation is to use that library!It is very useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ref` on your PaymentComponent like:

```
<stripe-payment ref="dialog"></stripe-payment>
```

In PaymentComponent, define an `open` method:

```
methods: {
  open() {
    this.paymentDialog = true
  }
}
```

Then on the other components, call this `open` method from `$root.$refs`:

```
methods: {
  openPayment() {
    this.$root.$refs['dialog'].open()
  }
}
```

[Vuetify fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/uu0t3gv0/)